# UWP Access to the Installed Location is denied

Tags: c#, uwp

I want to create an file inside a file in InstalledLocation to save the downloaded json String. But it gives an Exception as `System.UnauthorizedAccessException in System.Private.CoreLib.dll`. broadFileAccess Permissions is not also working and i tried runFullTrust too.

I get the error in the line

```
var NewFile = await localFolder.CreateFileAsync(@"DownloadedUpdate.json");
```

This is my code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;
using static Osumen_ChatKnoladgeBase.Trainer.ModelHandler;
using Windows.Storage;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

// The Blank Page item template is documented at https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=234238

namespace OsumenChatAI
{
    public class UpdateData
    {
        public object SentFrom { get; set; }
        public object Data { get; set; }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class UpdateInfo : Page
    {
        public UpdateInfo()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        var param = (UpdateData)e.Parameter;
        var page = param.SentFrom as MainPage;
        var NewUpdate = param.Data as Intent[];

        Task.Run(async()=> await ApplyUpdate(page, NewUpdate));

    }

    private async Task ApplyUpdate(MainPage page, Intent[] intents)
    {
        var localFolder = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation;
        var folderPath = localFolder.Path;
        var NewFile = await localFolder.CreateFileAsync(@"DownloadedUpdate.json");
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to create an file inside a file in InstalledLocation to save the downloaded json String. But it gives an Exception as System.UnauthorizedAccessException in System.Private.CoreLib.dll.

In UWP platform the app's [`InstalledLocation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions#application-install-directory)  directory is a read-only location. It is for deploy application code and assets.

If you need to access the created file , you cannot place it in the app's `InstalledLocation`. Please use app [`LocalFolder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.applicationdata.localfolder?view=winrt-20348) to replace.

```
StorageFolder localFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
```

For more please refer [**Application data locations**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions#application-data-locations)
official documentation.